# ¿Cómo tiro dobles en un Monopoly? Java

Tags: java, random, diseño-de-clases

Tengo que hacer un Monopoly en Java y estoy atascado en la clase que tengo que crear para lanzar los dados.
He conseguido escribir el código para el lanzamiento de los dados (gracias a una pregunta de otra persona que encontré en este foro) y, hasta ahí, todo bien. El problema viene a la hora de sacar dobles.
Como bien sabreis, una de las reglas del Monopoly dice que si lanzas los dos dados y obtienes dobles, puedes lanzarlos otra vez. Pues bien, no sé cómo implementar eso en mi código y es por eso que pregunto por aquí si alguien sabría explicarme cómo.
Dejo aquí el código para que me digáis:

```
package monopoly;

import java.util.Random;

public class LanzarDados {

    public static  int lanzarDados(int dados, int caras)
    {
        Random  r = new Random();
        int num = 0, lanzamiento = 0;
        if(caras >=2)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < dados; i++)
            {
                lanzamiento = r.nextInt(caras)+1;
                System.out.println("El lanzamiento es:  "+lanzamiento);
                num = num + lanzamiento;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("El total de los dados lanzados es: 
\n"+lanzarDados(2, 6));
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo más entendible quité la variable caras, asumiendo que solo habrá dados de 6 lados, y se establecen lanzamiento de 2 dados por vez, quedando así.

```
package monopoly;

import java.util.Random;

public class LanzarDados {

    public static int lanzarDados()
    {
        Random  r = new Random();
        int num = 0;

        bool repetido = true;
        while (repetido == true){
            int lanzamiento1 = 0;
            int lanzamiento2 = 0;
            lanzamiento1 = r.nextInt(6)+1;
            System.out.println("El lanzamiento 1 es:  "+lanzamiento1);
            lanzamiento2 = r.nextInt(6)+1;
            System.out.println("El lanzamiento 2 es:  "+lanzamiento2);
            num = num + lanzamiento1 + lanzamiento2;

            if (lanzamiento1 == lanzamiento2){
                System.out.println("Iguales, lanzar otra vez");
            }
            else{
                repetido = false;
            }
        }        
        return num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("El total de los dados lanzados es: 
\n"+lanzarDados());
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Ahora ya me queda mucho más claro.